# Duda para mostrar un valor calculado en un input readonly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, readonly

tengo un formulario donde selecciono a través de un  un producto determinado, con el cual muestro en otro  sus lotes y deseo mostrar en un input readonly (solo mostrar, no para ser editado), el valor del promedio de ese producto seleccionado. Tengo una función en javascript pero no se como mostrarlo en ese input, porque con la consola si obtengo el valor, alguien me puede ayudar?

[image: Formulario explicado]
[image: Resultado en consola]

Este es el código HTML del formulario donde muestro la tabla para seleccionar el producto. Esta tabla es dinamica, puedo agregar hasta 5 renglones para seleccionar productos. Me funciona bien

```
        <td>
            <select class="form-control id_producto" data-id_producto="1" id="id_producto1" name="id_producto[]">
                <option selected>Seleccione...</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($data3 as $dat3){
                        $id_producto = $dat3['id_producto'];
                        $desc_producto = $dat3['desc_producto_lab'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $id_producto; ?>">
                    <?php echo $desc_producto; ?>
                </option>
            <?php }?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control id_lote" data-id_lote="1" id="id_lote1" name="id_lote[]">
                <option>Seleccione...</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control precio_promedio" data-precio_promedio="1" type="number" id="precio_promedio1" name="precio_promedio[]" readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="cant_venta" name="cant_venta[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary addItemBtn" id="addItemBtn">(+)</button></td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
    <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-10" id="addVenta" name="addVenta">
            Registrar venta
        </button>
    </center>
```

Este es la función javascript que uso, la primera es para obtener los lotes del producto, me funciona bien, y la segunda la uso para obtener el precio promedio, es donde tengo la duda de como hacerlo

```
$(document).on('change', '.id_producto', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_producto = $(this).val();
    var lote = $(this).data("id_producto");
    var id_vendedor = document.getElementById("id_vendedor").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_productos_asig.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        method: "POST",
        data: {id_producto:id_producto, id_vendedor:id_vendedor},
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#id_lote"+lote).html(data);
    });  
});

$(document).on('change', '.id_producto', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_producto = $(this).val();
    var num = $(this).data("id_producto");
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_promedio.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        method: "POST",
        data: {id_producto:id_producto},
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#precio_promedio"+num).html(data);
    });  
});
```

Y este es el archivo get_promedio.php, recibo el id del producto para posteriormente hacer la consulta en la base de datos y obtener el promedio de ese producto

```
$id_producto = (isset($_POST['id_producto'])) ? $_POST['id_producto'] : '';

include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

// SQL PARA MOSTRAR LOS LOTES EN STOCK DE UN PRODUCTO
$datos_productos = "SELECT detalle_compra.id_producto,
                            productos.nombre_producto,
                            ROUND(AVG(precio_unit),2) AS promedio_producto
                    FROM detalle_compra, productos
                    WHERE detalle_compra.id_producto = '$id_producto'
                    AND detalle_compra.id_producto = productos.id_producto";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($datos_productos);
$resultado->execute();
$data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($data as $dat){

    echo $dat['promedio_producto'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor te falta un:

```
group by  detalle_compra.id_producto,
productos.nombre_producto
```

En la consulta SQL:

```
SELECT detalle_compra.id_producto,
       productos.nombre_producto,
       ROUND(AVG(precio_unit),2) AS promedio_producto
       FROM detalle_compra, productos
       WHERE detalle_compra.id_producto = '$id_producto'
       AND detalle_compra.id_producto = productos.id_producto

       group by  detalle_compra.id_producto,
       productos.nombre_producto
```

Comment: el problema no es el query, yo obtengo el resultado con el query, el problema es para devolver el valor al input. Gracias igual